# Serving a custom HttpHandler files with Cassini in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, httphandler, less

Just playing around with our `Less` `HttpHandler` for CSS preprocessing using Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NETMVC 2 and I am unable to serve the `.Less` file type how I'd like to.

I have added a handler section to the `web.config` which is all that was previously required with VS 2008 when using Cassini:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" validate="false" path="*.Less" verb="*"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

With VS2010 the file is being served as plain text. Is additional information required by the MVC framework or the Cassini change with 2010?

Edit:

I don't really care about finding anyway to serve Less files with VS2010 (I know about the T4 template). I'm trying to find out specifically why serving the HttpHandler fails.

Comment: With VWD 2010 Express your config is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need?

[T4CSS: A T4 Template for .Less CSS With Compression](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/02/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx)

It effectively generates minified CSS files for each `.less` file. This should give you the benefits of .less, along with having them being transformed into ordinary CSS files!

Comment: I was wondering if he was using .Less because of that post from Phil :) I've never heard of it until i read his post yesterday.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Nope, I one of the core developers on the .Less team so I knew about it well before then :-).

Comment: @Owen - Given this way of doing it, have you thought about the possibility packaging Phil's T4 into your project, and then simply serving the css files that are created as a result of the transformation? This would completely negate the need for having steps 3 & 4 on your home page - http://www.dotlesscss.com/

Comment: @Dan - Phils T4 template IS now part of our project as is an exisiting standalone .exe. But there are several use cases where the HtttpHandler is useful and some people (me included) prefer this option. 

Either way, the issue I am having is not related to .Less, it is simply how to server a custom HttpHandler with VS2010 and Cassini.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Http Handler even being called?  I don't have much experience with IIS7 specifically, but I do know that only certain file/request types are routed to the ASP.NET pipeline (such as .aspx and .ascx).

If the webserver isn't configured to send .less requests to asp.net then your .net Http Handler won't get a look in.

I'm assuming the HTTP Handler you refer to is a .net one you've written - but it would be the case for any handler.

Comment: The question isn't about IIS7 though. It's about Cassini.

Comment: @Dan - bingo!! The issue I am having is not when deploying it is when using the building Cassini webserver with VS2010